# Error when trying to log in: ORA-12154

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper, ora-12154

I am using Oracle 10*g* and PL/SQL Developer for the development. I have already tested from Net Manager that the database can be connected to, but when I tried to connect with PL/SQL Developer there was problem that I do not understand:

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

I have already searched for solution for the problem but still it can't be resolved. Any advice?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpjSI.png]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a hard one.
tnsping works. tnsnames.ora is correct.
This post solved it for me:
http://sambitimes.blogspot.de/2010/10/ora-12154-error-in-windows-7.html

If installation path of PL/SQL-Developer contains brackets, it screws up...
This will not work with win7:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PLSQL Developer"

this does for me:
"C:\Program Files\PLSQL Developer"

I hope it helps for others.

Comment: Dirk, your answer really helps! I ran into the same issue and fortunately found your answer here. I just moved  the sub dir of plsql developer from  C:\Program Files (x86) to C:\Program Files and it's working now. Thank you and Nore.

Answer (score 0):

That usually means that the database name you specify is not in the tnsnames.ora file. If you open PL/SQL Developer you will find the option "support info" under the About menu.
This has an entry such as this:

```
TNS File
  D:\Oracle\Designer\net80\admin\tnsnames.ora
```

Make sure your database is in this file.

Comment: I think i would use other tools, and i have  try to use Oracle SQL Developer, and its work!, but thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14219/tnsus.htm#sthref14854) says:

**Cause:** A connection to a database or other service was requested using a connect identifier, and the connect identifier specified could not be resolved into a connect descriptor using one of the naming methods configured. For example, if the type of connect identifier used was a net service name then the net service name could not be found in a naming method repository, or the repository could not be located or reached.

Are you trying to connect to the database the same way from Net Manager and PL/SQL Developer?

Comment: yes of course, when i tried from Net Manager, there was successful connected

Comment: I think i would use other tools, and i have  try to use Oracle SQL Developer, and its work!, but thanks! :)